# How to transition to a ui-router state in unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router with AngularJS.

I have a parent state called `root` with URL `/` which is linked to `RootCtrl` controller.
The `root` state has 2 children, named `root.about` and `root.contact` which are at URLs `root.about` and `root.contact` respectively. I'm trying to transition to the child states and assert that a scope property is set by their controllers in my jasmine tests but I'm not able to make the tests pass.

Here's a [demo on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lceVRH0F81M5q0xBb5tr?p=preview) . The demo has 2 failing tests, how can I make them pass ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot share the scope variable for your tests, they are instantiated differrently by the angular framework for each controller. Yes, they are inherited by child states, but instantiated differently

I made a new plunkr that works for your case:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RaZ34s?p=preview

Comment: Looks like `state.go` is not doing anything there. Commenting out those lines doesn't make the tests fail. I was expecting `state.go` to transition to that state and execute the controller code which doesn't happen. Any idea ?

Comment: [Here's a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Psuj4i?p=preview) to show what I mean. I expect the test to pass, because I am expecting state transition to reinstantiate the controller.

Comment: I think you're right. what we are testing there is the controller's initialization code, that is why it passed. In a ui-router, the controller is instantiated by the routing framework, so I do not think that you should test the controller's scope here. That should be on a different jasmine test. What you need to test is the state's URL. See this for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433485/angular-ui-router-unit-testing-states-to-urls and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19282006/tetsing-angularjs-ui-router-go-method

Comment: Thanks for sharing the links. Still not clear why ui-router does not instantiate controllers during state transitions in tests. I've posted a new question about this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216310/state-go-of-ui-router-doesnt-work-in-tests